# Make floated divs fill entire parent width

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

On my page, I need to display 10 boxes across it horizontally. Each box has a min-width of 150px and a max-width of 299px. The page should fit as many boxes as it can across the page without leaving any gaps, with each box having the same width (extending a pixel if needed due to rounding).

Example: If the width of the page is 660px, 4 boxes at 165px width should be used.
If the width of the page is 600px, 4 boxes at 150px width should be used.
If the width is 597px, 3 boxes at 199px should be used, since a box cannot go under 150px.

The remaining boxes on the bottom should have the same width of the ones above.

How can I accomplish the above?

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CD4f2/1/

Note how the rows of boxes leave a gap to the right.

using the follow code (because I'm forced to)

```
<body>
<div id="mainPage">
    <div id="bar">Width of a row of boxes should match the length of this bar.</div>
    <div id="capTable">
        <div class="cap" id="cap0">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap" id="cap2">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap" id="cap4">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap" id="cap6">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap" id="cap8">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="cap">
            <img class="capImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body 
{
    background-color:black;
}

.cap 
{
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 299px;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.capImage 
{
    background-color:blue;
    float: left;
    height: 37px;
    width: 37px;
}

#bar 
{
    background-color: orange;
}

#cap0, #cap2, #cap4, #cap6, #cap8 
{
    background-color: green;
}

#mainPage 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

I've tried this with tables also but ran into the same problems, as well as many different combination of floats, and displays, and overflows.

I believe I might be able to do this by manually specifying different resolutions in the CSS. But A more automatic approach would be preferred if possible.

I only want to use javascript as a last resort. Which I should be able to do myself.

Thanks.

Comment: You should actually formulate a question.

Comment: Seemed like it would be easy enough to determine, but I have added it nevertheless. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to offer a responsive layout and you are having trouble with figuring out how it is done. I find that using % widths is the cleanest solution so you could have 25% width divs then use a media response to change them to 50%. If that doesn't make sense then try looking at some example of good responsive frameworks. I use http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changes your .cap divs to use % widths instead of px to make it easier to get a responsive layout.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CD4f2/3/)

Main CSS Change

```
.cap 
{
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .cap {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like that will be the most appropriate method for my case, and that will work fine. Thanks. Hopefully one day we can have something better than HTML/CSS.